# @vue/cli and unit tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tdd, vue-cli

I am running @vue/cli it is version 4.5.15. I am wanting to write some tests for my components when I run,

`yarn test:unit`

I get an error

> ERROR command "test:unit" does not exist.

Is there some further setup I need to get unit testing running?

Answer (score 1):

Run `vue add @vue/unit-jest` in the project route that seems to have got them running.